# Why am I unable to manipulate my form object in the state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to manipulate my form object within my state in an immutable way upon user insertion.

I tried manipulating the property of the state of my form object upon user input, but it doesn't seem to work. I tried adding in another property in the state which is outside the form object in order to see whether the problem will persist which didn't. So, I am now left to think that my object traversing might be incorrect or I am missing something too obvious.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

import * as actions from '../../../store/actions/index'
import {Paper, Typography,Button} from '@material-ui/core'
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';



class SignUp extends Component{

state={
        formControl:{
            username:{
                value:'',
                placeHolder: 'Username',
                validation:{
                    required: true
                },
                touched:false,
                valid:false,
            },
            email:{
                value:'',
                placeHolder: 'E-mail',
                validation:{
                    required: true
                },
                touched:false,
                valid:false,
            },
            password:{
                value:'',
                placeHolder: 'Password',
                validation:{
                    required: true,
                    minLength:5,
                    maxLength:9
                },
                touched:false,
                valid:false,
            },
            confirmPassword:{
                value:'',
                placeHolder: 'Confirm Password',
                validation:{
                    required: true
                },
                touched:false,
                valid:false,
            },
            // hold:''
        }


}

inputHandler=(event, identifier)=> {

    const updatedState={...this.state.formControl}

    const updatedFormControl={
        ...updatedState[identifier]
    }
    // console.log(updatedFormControl.value= event.target.value)

    updatedFormControl.value= event.target.value
    console.log(updatedFormControl.value)


    this.setState({formControl:updatedState  })



}
render(){
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return(
        <Paper className={classes.root}>
        <Typography variant='h4'> Sign Up</Typography>
            <form className={classes.container} action="">
                <TextField
                    required
                    id="username"
                    label="Username"
                    className={classes.textField}
                    value={this.state.formControl.username.value}
                    onChange={(event)=>this.inputHandler(event,'username')}
                    margin="normal"
                />
                 <TextField
                    required
                    id="standard-name"
                    label="E-mail"

                    className={classes.textField}
                    margin="normal"
                    />
                     <TextField
                    required
                    id="standard-name"
                    label='Password'

                    className={classes.textField}
                    margin="normal"
                 />
                    <TextField
                    required
                    id="standard-name"
                    label='Confirm Password'

                    className={classes.textField}
                    margin="normal"
                 />
                 <Button variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.button}>  Sign Up  </Button>
        </form>
        </Paper>

    )
}
```

}

After all my attempts, I logged the property I wanted to manipulate to the console and kept seeing an empty string just the way it was initialized. I really can't seem to figure out what I am missing here guy. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set `updatedState` to formControl which is not changed

Change inputHandler like

```
inputHandler = (event, identifier) => {

    const updatedState = {...this.state.formControl,
        [identifier]: {...this.state.formControl[identifier], value: event.target.value}
    };

    console.log(updatedState)


    this.setState({formControl: updatedState})


}
```

Comment: Ahh thanx aseferov!! You are a lifesaver. But why do you think my approach doesn't work?

Comment: With your apporach, you create new object `updatedFormControl` from `updatedState` and set input value for it.  So `updateState` still same not updated. Then you set `updateState` as new value of state.formControl

Comment: Oh, I understand! I thought I was passing down the reference of updatedState. Thanks again for shedding more light on this.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are updating your state 
    `this.setState({formControl:updatedState  })` but `updatedState` is set to `this.state.formControl` so it's stuck in a recursive update. Perhaps you want to set it to `updatedFormControl`

Comment: updatedFormControl is only a copied slice of the object. If I set it to the state as a whole, it is going to return an error.